# How to use a batch command to copy all folders to a destination location

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following line in a bat file:

```
xcopy script_temp\* \\CHU-Computer-Science\CHU\scripts\ /S /E /H
```

however, this will only copy files, how can i also have it copy the folder?

Comment: Works on my local machine (Windows 7)

Comment: @SpectralGhost , yes, it is working for me now as well after i took the trailing slash off of the 'scripts' folder in the destination location. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options you used copied empty folders for me on Vista. I don't know if there are differences in versions of Windows.

The /S and /E are mutually exclusive. /E copies subfolders, including empty ones. /S copies subfolders but ignores empty ones.

I thought that the last option specified wins, so the command you used should work. You could try eliminating the /S option and see if that helps on your system.

Or possibly I don't understand your question?

Comment: Hi, well i thought it would work like this, and it does when i take that trailing slash off of the 'scripts' directory, thank you for looking, i am new to S/O, maybe i can delete or show this was the problem?